# python: How can I write a test for this function?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, typeerror

I have my function and testing part.

testing part,
But I get this kind of error, how can I fix it, do I need to use type casting?

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

For example I have in my file aa-bb-cc. It means that I have 3 fields, and if I want to get true I need to pass fields_number=3

Comment: post full traceback you get.  I doubt it's related to that part of your code. Also note that  `func` expects `fields_number` keyword argument and in the test you pass `num_fileds`.

Comment: Sorry,This was my fault, I forgot to change it here. but my problem is in the parametrize part, because this function works when I just call this function and give parameters. @buran

Comment: please, don't remove important content of the question rendering it useless.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the first argument you pass to decorator - `'file_name, fields_number=None, sep='-', expected_result'`.

Because of the `'-'` it looks like substracting 2 strings: `'file_name, fields_number=None, sep='` and `', expected_result'`. Not sure you need to include the default values, but if you do use double quotes, not single quotes around a string that has single quotes inside it.

EDIT: This should work:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('file_name, fields_number, sep, expected_result',
                         [('file_prog', 5, '-', True),
                          ('file_prog', None ,'-', False)])
def test_func(file_name, fields_name, sep, expected_result):
    result = func(file_name=file_name, fields_number=fields_number, sep=sep)
    assert result == expected_result
```

You can replace first argument of the decorator with list:

`['file_name', 'fields_number', 'sep', 'expected_result']`

Comment: You mean something like this?  ` [('file_prog', 5, " '-' ", True), ('file_prog', None ," '-' ", False)])` @buran

Comment: Thanks, I will try it now) @buran